# Facebook share redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the facebook share dialog from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Now i created my URL and it works:

```
https: //facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup&caption=Mein%20selbst%20erstelltes%20Moebelstueck%20 
  &link=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-url.de
  &redirect_uri=https ://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-moebelstueck.de/fb/'.$pictureurl.'.png&description=Gestalte deine Moebel selbst!&caption=3D MÃ¶belkonfigurator&description=Ich habe mir ein MÃ¶belstÃ¼ck erstellt! Probiere es doch auch mal aus!
```

This works good but I have one Problem:
if i change the redirect_uri=https ://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to another URL like www.example.com it crashed. 
Can you help me? What do i wrong: i tried it with several URL's but everytime facebook said: "there is an Mistake". What can I do? is there a special secret. It just fit with this URL. if i use https ://developers. facebook.com/ tools is also crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the app_id for the Graph Explorer, which requires that redirect_uri must go to the Graph Explorer.

To redirect somewhere else you must create your own Facebook Application via the [Facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). You probably want to set up the application as a Website with Facebook Login, and then you can post with your app_id and a redirect_uri going to your website.